# Excel: text-to-columns anomaly

Tags: excel, csv

I have a large-ish pipe delimited CSV file which is causing me some serious trouble. It has data until column FM, so more than 150 columns, and 6496 rows.

1. Opening the file in a text editor, shows **6496** lines.
2. Renaming the file to a .txt file, the open with text importer, shows **6496** lines.
3. Opening the CSV file in Excel, then use text-to-columns functionality, shows **6490** lines.

Somehow, 6 lines go missing.

I am using Excel 2007 on Windows 7, on this particular computer, but the client is using Excel 2013 on Windows 8.1, so it is not a "version" thing, as far as I can tell, unless both versions are affected.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps some lines are combined when you open the .csv?  I would import into Excel, in both ways, and then do a line by line comparison; then examine closely the "missing" lines.

Comment: Thanks, Ron. Strange though that importing in different means in Excel would yield different results? Excel bug perhaps?

Comment: I would more likely suspect a subtle difference in the data-- perhaps the EOL character on a few lines.  Also, with CSV you are OPENing the file; with TXT you are Importing the file -- two different processes.  The IMPORT process is more flexible.  But without seeing the actual data, hard to say.

Comment: Hi Ron, yes, found the problem - it is a subtle difference in the data. Explanation: double clicking the file opens with "default" delimiter (comma). The first row with an issue, ended with a comma, meaning that by double clicking, that row had two columns for that row. Opening as text file never opens the file until you actually set the delimiter. Solution was to add `rtrim(trim($value), ',');`  on the value before exporting. I needed the trim() because that line also had a space after the comma. NEVER trust user data... Please submit your original comment as an answer, and I will accept it.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes the CSV files have to be well-formed in order to work properly with the standard settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps some lines are combined when you open the .csv? I would import into Excel, in both ways, and then do a line by line comparison; then examine closely the "missing" lines.

I would suspect some subtle difference in the lines -- perhaps something that is causing the EOL to be misinterpreted when you OPEN the CSV file.